# Huge table of post like status, select random from top 100

Tags: php, mysql, select, random, schema

I have a table which hold the post like statuses.
table columns are :

```
ID        //which is unique incremental
Post_id   //liked post
user_id   //user who gave like or dislike
type      //"1","0" or "2" which stands for Liked, neutral or disliked.
```

here is example data

```
+--------+---------+---------+------+
| id     | post_id | user_id | type |
+--------+---------+---------+------+
| 938300 |  347298 |     661 |    0 |
| 938299 |  346185 |       0 |    1 |
| 938298 |  347286 |    2645 |    0 |
| 938297 |  346924 |     374 |    1 |
| 938296 |  347261 |    1523 |    1 |
| 938295 |  347313 |    3233 |    1 |
| 938294 |  346323 |    1375 |    1 |
| 938293 |  347022 |    1779 |    1 |
| 938292 |  347278 |    2645 |    1 |
| 938291 |  347300 |     109 |    1 |
+--------+---------+---------+------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

however this query runs flawless but as you guys can see there are hundreds of data in this table. What I need is :

```
SELECT post_id, 
       count(post_id) 
FROM   'table'
WHERE  type = '1' 
GROUP  BY post_id 
ORDER  BY count(post_id) 
LIMIT  300;
```

this query selects most liked 300 posts, and php code select randomly one from it. However this query has full table scan it proceeds over 5 seconds. how can I speed this up or Do I have to change table scheme?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for caching.

Comment: Well, this calculation is expensive, but in theory the result will not change all that often (especially if these are the most liked all time). So run the query, and then save the result somewhere - and then in your application access the result, which should be instantaneous.

Comment: well great idea. Never thought about it, I may make a cron update the results once per week. well thanks for this solution

Comment: For your specific need, it might make sense to actually have a "like" counter on the posts table; that way, you can actually get the information you want in one simple query.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to gain some speedup by using indexes. You're query is expensive computation-wise so caching may be the better answer. See if having either or both of these indexes helps your table:

```
CREATE INDEX post_id_index ON `table` (post_id);
CREATE INDEX type_index ON `table` (type);
```

If not then delete them with:

```
DROP INDEX post_id_index ON `table`;
DROP INDEX type_index ON `table`;
```

Make sure to drop them if they do not help, but give them a few tries beforehand just to be sure. Another option if caching is not for you is to keep another table of just that result. I think that may have already been suggested. I suggest the indexes because it is super easy to just create them them. Just run each as a complete SQL command and see if the query in question is faster. Here is some more information on indexes:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: thanks, i can see now indexing can make a huge difference, really huge. However my table already had them but i think my query can never use them because i guess it has to make full table scan. Like @Mansfield said, caching is the best solution for this case

Comment: @AkainuLionheart Right so this seemed like it was going to be the case since you are asking for count, so a full scan is needed. Just thought I would throw it out there in case it could help. Caching is probably the most robust solution indeed.